# Reactivity of thiosemicarbazide

Tags: organic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, synthesis

How to form Schiff's Base at both the ends of the thiosemicarbazide?
$\ce{NH2}$ of hydrazine part reacts easily to form Schiff's base i.e. imine. But $\ce{NH2}$ attached to $\ce{C=S}$ does not. How to do that?
One approach is by using NCS but that forms imine at $\ce{NH2}$ attached to $\ce{C=S}$ only and not at the other end.

[image: thiosemicarbazide]

Comment: (thio)amides have extremely low nucleofility, I think it is impractical to try for the shiff base you want directly, it better to try inderect approach

Comment: I have read papers which say thioamide is more reactive than amides.  Could you suggest any indirect methods?